# print logs for the linted files with `ng lint` command

Tags: angular, eslint

For my investigation I want `ng lint` - which is part of the quite developed Angular CLI - to print touched files. I want to see if it processes `node_modules` under various configurations.

Previously, I figured out that I can make ESLint become more verbose with the following command:

```bash
export DEBUG="eslint:*,-eslint:code-path"
```

The official documentation does not show any related flags for the [command](https://angular.io/cli/lint).
The [reporting package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lint-report) also does not effect the "versbosity".

Question: how to make `ng lint` print the files it is processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This eslint plugin could help [eslint-plugin-log-filenames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-log-filenames)