# Gitlab runner times out while running lint command

Tags: node.js, angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following GitLab CI step:

```
lint:
  stage: frontend_check
  only:
    changes:
      - frontend/**/*
  script:
    - cd frontend/ngapp
    - npm run lint
    - npm run prettier
```

Running this on GitLab will time out after two hours.

[image: screenshot of formatted output]

The raw log:

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 16.4.0 (6e766faf)[0;m
[0K  on runner-192.168.63.53 U-zL7nfx, system ID: s_351d454b0ffc[0;m
section_start:1702987831:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker" executor[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing Docker executor with image node:21.4.0 ...[0;m
[0KAuthenticating with credentials from /root/.docker/config.json[0;m
[0KPulling docker image node:21.4.0 ...[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:b866e35a0dc4df85e168524b368567023eb22b06fe16f2237094e937fcd24d96 for node:21.4.0 with digest node@sha256:52206db44f7bb76dca465a9fae016922b6878c39261c87c9b719ae4d892fecfd ...[0;m
section_end:1702987834:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1702987834:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m[0;m
Running on runner-u-zl7nfx-project-425-concurrent-0 via gitlab-runner...
section_end:1702987835:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1702987835:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m[0;m
[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 50...[0;m
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/ivu/landshut/.git/
[32;1mChecking out b6b09e82 as detached HEAD (ref is master)...[0;m
Removing frontend/ngapp/

[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1702987841:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1702987841:download_artifacts
[0K[0K[36;1mDownloading artifacts[0;m[0;m
[32;1mDownloading artifacts for maven_compile (635434)...[0;m
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok      [0;m  host[0;m=gitlab.webvalto.hu id[0;m=635434 responseStatus[0;m=200 OK token[0;m=64_xgXce
[32;1mDownloading artifacts for install_dependencies (635435)...[0;m
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok      [0;m  host[0;m=gitlab.webvalto.hu id[0;m=635435 responseStatus[0;m=200 OK token[0;m=64_xgXce
section_end:1702987878:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_start:1702987878:step_script
[0K[0K[36;1mExecuting "step_script" stage of the job script[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:b866e35a0dc4df85e168524b368567023eb22b06fe16f2237094e937fcd24d96 for node:21.4.0 with digest node@sha256:52206db44f7bb76dca465a9fae016922b6878c39261c87c9b719ae4d892fecfd ...[0;m
[32;1m$ cd frontend/ngapp[0;m
[32;1m$ npm run lint[0;m

> customer-webportal-fe@1.0.2 lint
> ng lint --fix

Node.js version v21.4.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases/.
section_end:1702995031:step_script
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 2h0m0s seconds
[0;m
```

Running the same command on my machine with the same Node version completes in 5 seconds.

[image: screenshot of my terminal running the same command]

**Update:** `npm install` is done in a spearate job, and the folder is passed as an artifact. Adding the `npm install` command just in case directly to this job, did not solve the issue either.

[image: 15 minutes into running npm run lint]

**update 2:**
I have registered my local machine as a runner and tried to run the job on it.

I saw in the `top` that when the job arrived ad the  `ng lint` command, that the `node` process ran for a short period, then disappeared (hopefully meaning that the command was done) then the whole runner just hang forever, with leaving my PC in idle status.
[image: screenshot of my two bash windows, one with the docker-runner logs one with the top command]
[image: screenshot of the gitlab gui at the same time]

`.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json"],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case",
            "type": "element"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase",
            "type": "attribute"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell why the process is hanging from the output you're providing. If you run `npm run lint` locally instead of the `ng lint --fix` one directly, does that give a different output?

Comment: Make sure to review your GitLab Runner settings, especially if you have any special configurations or restrictions that could be impacting how your tasks are running. If you're running several jobs at the same time, try decreasing the number of jobs running simultaneously to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Try using `npm ci` to install the deps. Perhaps, there is a mismatch in the installed packages versions which causes this behavior differences. Also, I'd try using the LTS Node. Just to be sure you don't get any bugs because of some Node & package. Also, you could try running the lint command directly without the CLI. Another thing I would test is running `ng lint` with `CI=true` on local machine, just in case. BTW, are you sure `--fix` is the flag you want to use in the pipelines? Usually, pipelines aren't supposed to change any files in the repo.

Comment: You may also want to run the command via `npx`. To make sure the local Angular CLI is used. There are some reports that global/installed CLI mismatch can cause this.

Comment: @thomaux replacing the `npm run lint` command with a direct ` CI=true ng lint --fix` resulted in the same timeout

Comment: @moh tried to run only this job alone, same timeout.

Comment: @Sergey tried `npm ci` and got the same timeout results. I tried your other methods as well. you are right, the `--fix` is obsolete here, but omitting it resulted the same result.

Comment: If you run `ng v` before the lint, is the version printed the same as you have in package.json? There is also a chance that updating packages could "magically" fix the issue.

Comment: Do you use ESLint or TSLint under the hood? Have you tried `--verbose` flag to have a richer output? You might also want to enable some verbose logging for Node itself. Perhaps it has some issues with opening files (e.g. they could be locked by some process or smth). Another thing to try is to comment out all lint rules/plugins and enable them 1-by-1 to see if it's a specific rule/plugin that is causing the issue. You may also want to clear the cache locally and `npm ci`. You should have the same behavior with the CI on your local machine.

Comment: Its suspicious that you don't even get `Linting "XXX"...` message. Something fails early, try to remove `.angular` and `node_modules` dirs locally and test, maybe you'll see the same problem. Do you use new esbuild builder? If runner hangs it means that node process or some child process is still running, check what they do (name, command line). Try to use cache key in .yaml file.

Comment: @Sergey `ng v` prints out the same version.

Comment: @Sergey the `ng lint` does not have a `--verbose` flag. https://angular.io/cli/lint

Comment: @Sergey could not find any specific rules which could acuse the problem. Due to it being an angular project, without the default extensions, the linting won't run successfully. I attached it to the original question

Comment: @Sergey yes, we upgraded to angular 17 just a few days ago, and this issue appeared right away. We tried using caching (and not using) but it had the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full gitlab template I was working with was:

```
image: node:21.4.0

stages:
  - maven_init # basic maven initialization
  - frontend_init # create frontend node environment for build
  - frontend_check # static checks before build
  - frontend_build # build the frontend app
  - pages # create documentation
  - test-server-deploy # deploy to test environment
  - e2e # isolated stage to test the currently deployed version on the  test server.
  - sonarqube-check # SonarQube code analysis

maven_compile:
  image: maven:latest
  needs: []
  stage: maven_init
  script:
    - mvn clean install -Ptest
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./frontend/ngapp/
  except:
    variables:
      - $RUN_E2E == "true"
      - $DEPLOY_TEST == "true"

lint:
  stage: frontend_check
  script:
    - cd frontend/ngapp
    - echo "Checking Angular CLI version..."
    - ng v
    - npm ci
    - echo "Running lint without rules/plugins..."
    # Temporarily disable rules/plugins here
    - CI=true ng lint
    - echo "Linting process completed or failed."
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-node-modules
    paths:
      - node_modules/
```

As you can see, there is a step, which runs a maven install first. It basicly   runs a copy command (                           `<goal>copy-resources</goal>`), and copies the project from the `frontend/src/main/resources/ngapp` to `fronted/ngapp` folder (among other things to prepare the bundle for being deployed). We used it with no problems for a long time, but after upgrading to angular 17, for some reason, the problem happened.

Replacing `cd frontend/ngapp` with `frontend/src/main/resources/ngapp` (so, running the `ng lint` command at the original location of the project, not in the copied folder` fixed the issue.

Running the exaclty same job on the original folder, where the project exists  runs successfully. We are not sure why (tried different caching strategies; we run the npm install in the new folder, etc.) but it fixed the issue, and it does not get stuck anymore.

Comment: I've debugged gitlab for hours countless times, and love following others solutions. Thanks for the entertainment.

Answer (score 1):

So you have:

```bash
+-------------------+          +-------------------+
|                   |          |                   |
|   Local Machine   |   --->   |   GitLab Runner   |
|                   |          |                   |
| - Node.js v21.4.0 |          | - Docker Image    |
| - Linting: ~5 sec |          | - Node.js v21.4.0 |
|                   |          | - Linting: Timeout|
+-------------------+          +-------------------+
```

Check that `npm install` is run in the same job or make sure artifacts are properly passed between jobs.
Sometimes linting rules or a misconfiguration can cause the linter to enter an infinite loop.

Also, the GitLab runner might have resource constraints. Check the resources (CPU, memory) allocated to the runner.
Implement caching for `node_modules` to speed up the process. Temporarily increase the timeout setting to determine if the job eventually completes.

Your updated GitLab CI configuration would be:

```yaml
lint:
  stage: frontend_check
  only:
    changes:
      - frontend/**/*
  script:
    - cd frontend/ngapp
    - npm install # Make sure dependencies are installed
    - npm run lint
    - npm run prettier
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/ # Cache node_modules
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - frontend/ngapp/ # Make sure artifacts are passed if `npm install` is in a separate job
  timeout: 4h # Temporarily increase the timeout
```

Or:

```yaml
lint:
  image: node:current-lts # Use LTS version of Node.js
  stage: frontend_check
  only:
    changes:
      - frontend/**/*
  script:
    - cd frontend/ngapp
    - npm ci
    - CI=true npx ng lint # Use CI=true to mimic CI environment and npx to use local CLI
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
```

---

None of your suggestions worked, however, I replaced the command with what you said. I registered my pc as a GitLab runner (all settings on default) and ran it again, with the same results. I added new screenshots to the end of the question. Do you have any other suggestions? The Runner process did not show any useful log information.

From the comments, make sure the Angular CLI version (`ng v`) matches the version specified in `package.json` Check if updating all packages to the latest compatible versions could help.

Determine if ESLint or TSLint is being used. The `--verbose` flag may give more clues, and verbose logging for Node.js might expose file access issues or process locks. Note: there is no verbose option for [`ng lint`](https://angular.io/cli/lint), only an [eslint plugin '`eslint-plugin-log-filenames`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72797664/6309).
Commenting out lint rules and plugins, then reintroducing them one by one, can help identify if a specific configuration is causing the hang-up.

Clear the local cache and run `npm ci` to make sure a clean state both locally and in CI. Check if removing `.angular` and `node_modules` directories locally, and testing can help identify if stale or corrupted configurations are causing issues.

If the process is hanging, it implies a Node.js process or child process is still running. Check the running processes to see what they are doing (process name, command line arguments, etc.).

Use [cache keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` to make sure caches are properly created and restored.

```yaml
lint:
  stage: frontend_check
  script:
    - cd frontend/ngapp
    - echo "Checking Angular CLI version..."
    - ng v
    - npm ci
    - echo "Running lint without rules/plugins..."
    # Temporarily disable rules/plugins here
    - CI=true ng lint
    - echo "Linting process completed or failed."
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-node-modules
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - frontend/ngapp/
  only:
    changes:
      - frontend/**/*
```

And for local testing:

```bash
# Clear npm cache and remove directories
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf .angular node_modules

# Reinstall dependencies cleanly
npm ci

# Check running processes if linting hangs
ps aux | grep node

# Run linting
CI=true ng lint
```

---

As [mentioned by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77726291/6309), the resolution involved changing the directory from which the `ng lint` command was run. By executing the linting command in the original project directory (`frontend/src/main/resources/ngapp`) instead of the copied directory (`frontend/ngapp`), the issue was successfully resolved, and the linting process no longer hangs.

That does highlight some of the points I made above, like the importance of correctly handling caching and artifacts, and making sure the environment and directory structure in CI mirrors that of the local setup: it helps the investigation toward file and directory-related configurations.

Comment: thank you for the throorugh answer. None of you suggestion worked, however, I replaced the command with what you said. I registered my pc as a gitlab runner (all settings on default) and ran it again, with the same results. I added new screenshots to the end of the question. Do you have any other suggestions? the Runner process did not show any useful log information.

Comment: @ForestG OK, I have edited the answer to add some debug suggestions.

Comment: "Determine if ESLint or TSLint is being used. The --verbose flag may give more " -> the `ng lint` command does not support the verbose flag. https://angular.io/cli/lint

Comment: we found the problem. It was because of a caching, however, we still investigate the problem. I will accept your answer as your ideas helped me the most. I will write a short summary of what we found.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you haven't installed the `npm` dependencies yet. So the `ng` command is not known.

Try to make an `npm install` or `npm ci` before :

```
lint:
 stage: frontend_check
 only:
   changes:
     - frontend/**/*
 script:
   - cd frontend/ngapp
   - npm install
   - npm run lint
   - npm run prettier
```

but you can also use the caches and artifacts provided by your previous jobs for example like `.npm` and `node_modules`

Comment: I did omit it from the question - sorry for that - but the node install is done in a separate step and the folder is then passed as an artifact. 

If the ng command would be unknown, that I would get an error message (Command 'ng' not found, but can be installed with...) I think.

Comment: I have added the npm install step just in case, it did not solve the issue.